Uncaught TypeError: Node.appendChild: Argument 1 is not an object
I'm trying to debug a JavaScript code which supposed to save the data from a form after clicking on "Save Button" and the show a window with a progress bar (in percentage):
function ff_geninfo_section_savebutton_action(element, action) {

  switch (action) {

    case "click":

      // Delete any overlay if existing

      if (document.getElementById("loading-overlay")) {

        document.getElementById("loading-overlay").remove();

      }


      // Display the overlay with a progress bar and the message

      showLoadingOverlay('Saving data in progress, please wait...');


      // Progress Bar starting

      startProgressBar();


      jQuery.ajax({

        type: "POST",

        url: jQuery(element).closest("form").attr("action"),

        data: jQuery(element).closest("form").serialize(),

        success: function (data) {

          // Diplay form data in the console

          var formDataArray = jQuery(element).closest("form").serializeArray();

          console.log("Données du formulaire :", formDataArray);


          // Create an object to hold the inputs data

          var formData = {};


          jQuery.each(formDataArray, function (index, field) {

            // Delete the '[' et ']' from the field names

            var fieldName = field.name.replace(/\[\]/g, "");

            formData[fieldName] = field.value;

          });


          // Diplay the extracted data into the console

          console.log("Données envoyées avec succès :", formData);


          // Save the data in the localStorage

          localStorage.setItem("formData", JSON.stringify(formData));


          // Update the Overlay message and indicate that the data is saved

          updateLoadingOverlayMessage("Your data is saved !");

          

          // Complete the progression bar to 100%

          completeProgressBar();


          // Close the overlay loading after a few seconds

          setTimeout(function () {

            hideLoadingOverlay();

          }, 3000);

        },

      });

      break;

    default:

    // Other

  }

}


// Progression bar var

var progressBarInterval;

var progressBarElement;

var progressBarStartTime;


// Progression bar starting function

function startProgressBar() {

  // Progression Bar starting initialize

  progressBarStartTime = new Date().getTime();


  // Add the Div to the loading overlay

  var modalDiv = document.getElementById("loading-overlay");
  if (modalDiv) {
    modalDiv.appendChild(progressBarElement);
  }

  // Update the progress bar with regular intervals
  progressBarInterval = setInterval(function () {
    updateProgressBarWidth();
  }, 100);
}


// Progression bar stop function

function stopProgressBar() {

  // Delete the Div from the progresson bar

  if (progressBarElement) {

    progressBarElement.parentNode.removeChild(progressBarElement);

    progressBarElement = null; // Resetting variables

  }


  // Stop the interval of the progression bar updating

  clearInterval(progressBarInterval);

}


// Complete the progression bar to 100% function

function completeProgressBar() {

  if (progressBarElement) {

    progressBarElement.style.width = "100%";

    var progressPercent = document.getElementById("progress-percent");

    if (progressPercent) {

      progressPercent.innerHTML = "100%";

    }

  }

}


// Overlay with message and progress bar displaying function

function showLoadingOverlay(message) {

  // Dev for a overlay

  var overlayDiv = document.createElement("div");

  overlayDiv.id = "loading-overlay";

  overlayDiv.style.position = "fixed";

  overlayDiv.style.top = "0";

  overlayDiv.style.left = "0";

  overlayDiv.style.width = "100%";

  overlayDiv.style.height = "100%";

  overlayDiv.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)";

  overlayDiv.style.color = "white";

  overlayDiv.style.fontSize = "20px";

  overlayDiv.style.textAlign = "center";

  overlayDiv.style.paddingTop = "20%";

  overlayDiv.style.zIndex = "9999";


  // Message Div

  var messageDiv = document.createElement("div");

  messageDiv.id = "loading-message";

  messageDiv.innerHTML = message;

  messageDiv.style.marginBottom = "20px";


  // Progress bar container Div

  var progressContainer = document.createElement("div");

  progressContainer.id = "progress-container";

  progressContainer.style.width = "50%";

  progressContainer.style.height = "30px";

  progressContainer.style.backgroundColor = "#ddd";

  progressContainer.style.margin = "0 auto";

  progressContainer.style.borderRadius = "5px";

  progressContainer.style.overflow = "hidden";

  progressContainer.style.position = "relative";


  // Progress bar Div

  var progressBar = document.createElement("div");

  progressBar.id = "progress-bar";

  progressBar.style.width = "0%";

  progressBar.style.height = "100%";

  progressBar.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";


  // Percentage on bar displaying Div

  var progressPercent = document.createElement("div");

  progressPercent.id = "progress-percent";

  progressPercent.style.position = "absolute";

  progressPercent.style.top = "0";

  progressPercent.style.left = "0";

  progressPercent.style.width = "100%";

  progressPercent.style.height = "100%";

  progressPercent.style.display = "flex";

  progressPercent.style.alignItems = "center";

  progressPercent.style.justifyContent = "center";

  progressPercent.style.color = "#000";

  progressPercent.style.fontWeight = "bold";

  progressPercent.innerHTML = "0%";


  // Add progress bar and the percentage to a container

  progressContainer.appendChild(progressBar);

  progressContainer.appendChild(progressPercent);


  // Add a message and a container of the bar to the overlay window

  overlayDiv.appendChild(messageDiv);

  overlayDiv.appendChild(progressContainer);


  // Add overlay to the body

  document.body.appendChild(overlayDiv);


  // Update the progress bar

  progressBarInterval = setInterval(function () {

    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

    var elapsedTime = currentTime - progressBarStartTime;

    var progressPercentage = Math.min(100, (elapsedTime / (1 * 80 * 1000)) * 100);

    progressBar.style.width = progressPercentage + "%";

    progressPercent.innerHTML = Math.round(progressPercentage) + "%";


    if (progressPercentage >= 100) {

      clearInterval(progressBarInterval);

    }

  }, 100);

}


// Update the overlay message function

function updateLoadingOverlayMessage(message) {

  var messageDiv = document.getElementById("loading-message");

  if (messageDiv) {

    messageDiv.innerHTML = message;

  }

}


// Hide overlay function

function hideLoadingOverlay() {

  var overlay = document.getElementById("loading-overlay");

  if (overlay) {

    overlay.style.display = "none";

  }

}

Unfortunately data is not saved in the database and the progress bar is stucked as the overlay. In the console I have an error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Node.appendChild: Argument 1 is not an object.
startProgressBar /formulaires-inspection/fi15c:3391
ff_geninfo_section_savebutton_action /formulaires-inspection/fi15c:3173
onclick /formulaires-inspection/fi15c:1**
Line1:
if(typeof bf_htmltextareainit != 'undefined'){ bf_htmltextareainit() }populateSummarizers();if(document.getElementById('bfPaymentMethod')){document.getElementById('bfPaymentMethod').value='';};ff_geninfo_section_savebutton_action(this,'click');return false;

Line 3391:
progressBarStartTime=new Date().getTime();var modalDiv=document.getElementById("loading-overlay-6");if(modalDiv){modalDiv.appendChild(progressBarElement);}progressBarInterval=setInterval(function(){updateProgressBarWidth();},100);}function stopProgressBar(){

Line 3173:
startProgressBar();jQuery.ajax({type:"POST",url:jQuery(element).closest("form").attr("action"),data:jQuery(element).closest("form").serialize(),success:function(data){var formDataArray=jQuery(element).closest("form").serializeArray();console.log("Données du formulaire :",formDataArray);

I'm really embarrassed with this since few hours.
Thank you in advance.
Max.
Tried to debug but without succès:
const modalDiv = document.getElementById("loading-overlay");if (!modalDiv) {console.error("Element with ID 'loading-overlay' not found.");return; // Exit the function if modalDiv is not found}

// Ensure progressBarElement exists and is a valid DOM element
if (progressBarElement && progressBarElement instanceof HTMLElement) {modalDiv.appendChild(progressBarElement);} else {console.error("progressBarElement is not a valid DOM element.");return; // Exit the function if progressBarElement is not valid}

Here's the original working code with modal (popup) windows instead the bugged code with overlay:
function ff_geninfo_section_savebutton_action(element, action) {
  switch (action) {
    case "click":
      // Show modal window with loading message
      showLoadingModal('Data saving in progress...');
      // Start Progress Bar
      startProgressBar();

      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: jQuery(element).closest("form").attr("action"),
        data: jQuery(element).closest("form").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
          // Display form data in console
          var formDataArray = jQuery(element).closest("form").serializeArray();
          console.log("Données du formulaire :", formDataArray);

          // Create an object to store the input data
          var formData = {};

          jQuery.each(formDataArray, function (index, field) {
            // Remove brackets '[' and ']' from field names
            var fieldName = field.name.replace(/\[\]/g, "");
            formData[fieldName] = field.value;
          });

          // Display the extracted data in the console
          console.log("Données envoyées avec succès :", formData);

          // Save data to localStorage
          localStorage.setItem("formData", JSON.stringify(formData));

          // Hide the loading modal window
          hideLoadingModal();

          // Show confirmation modal window with message
          showModal("Your data is saved!");
          // Automatically close the confirmation modal window after a few seconds
          setTimeout(function () {
            hideModal();
          }, 3000); // adjust the duration in milliseconds as needed
          // ff_validate_nextpage();
          ff_getElementByName("finished").value = 0;
          // Stop the progress bar
          stopProgressBar();
        },
        error: function () {
         // Hide the loading modal window on error
          hideLoadingModal();
         // Display an error message in the confirmation modal
          showModal("Error saving data. Please try again.");
          // Stop the progress bar on error
          stopProgressBar();
        },
      });
      break;
    default:
    // Other case
  } // switch
}

// Variables for the progress bar
var progressBarInterval;
var progressBarElement;
var progressBarStartTime;

// Function to start the progress bar
function startProgressBar() {
  // Initialize the start time of the progress bar
  progressBarStartTime = new Date().getTime();

  // Create the div for the progress bar
  progressBarElement = document.createElement("div");
  progressBarElement.style.width = "0%";
  progressBarElement.style.height = "10px"; // Adjust the thickness of the bar
  progressBarElement.style.background =
    "linear-gradient(to right, #5b92a8 0%, #fff 0%)";
  progressBarElement.style.position = "fixed";
  progressBarElement.style.bottom = "10px";
  progressBarElement.style.left = "10px";
  progressBarElement.style.right = "10px";
  progressBarElement.style.borderRadius = "8px";
  progressBarElement.style.overflow = "hidden"; // Prevent progress bar from overflowing
  progressBarElement.style.maxWidth = "calc(100% - 20px)"; // Adjust width to avoid overflow

// Add the div to the modal window
  var modalDiv = document.getElementById("loadingModal");
  if (modalDiv) {
    modalDiv.appendChild(progressBarElement);
  }

  // Update the progress bar at regular intervals
  progressBarInterval = setInterval(function () {
    updateProgressBarWidth();
  }, 100);
}

// Function to stop the progress bar
function stopProgressBar() {
  // Remove the progress bar div
  if (progressBarElement) {
    progressBarElement.parentNode.removeChild(progressBarElement);
  }
// Stop the progress bar update interval
  clearInterval(progressBarInterval);
}

// Function to update the width of the progress bar
function updateProgressBarWidth() {
  if (progressBarElement) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var elapsedTime = currentTime - progressBarStartTime;
    var progressPercentage = (elapsedTime / (1 * 60 * 1000)) * 100;

    if (progressPercentage <= 100) {
      progressBarElement.style.width = progressPercentage + "%";
    } else {
      progressBarElement.style.width = "100%";
    }
  }
}

// Function to hide the loading modal window
function hideLoadingModal() {
 // Find the loading modal window div and hide it
  var modalDiv = document.getElementById("loadingModal");
  if (modalDiv) {
    modalDiv.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Function to hide the confirmation modal window
function hideModal() {
 // Find the confirmation modal window div and hide it
  var modalDiv = document.querySelector(".geninfosaveModal");
  if (modalDiv) {
    modalDiv.parentNode.removeChild(modalDiv);
  }
}

// Function to display the confirmation modal window with a messagee
function showModal(message) {
  // Create a div for the modal window with the message
  var modalDiv = document.createElement("div");
  modalDiv.className = "geninfosaveModal"; // Add a class for future reference
  modalDiv.style.position = "fixed";
  modalDiv.style.top = "50%";
  modalDiv.style.left = "50%";
  modalDiv.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)";
  modalDiv.style.background = "#74889b";
  modalDiv.style.padding = "20px";
  modalDiv.style.border = "1px solid #46596c";
  modalDiv.style.color = "#fff";
  modalDiv.innerHTML = message;

  // Add the div to the page
  document.body.appendChild(modalDiv);
}

// Function to display the loading modal window with a message
function showLoadingModal(message) {
  // Create a div for the modal window with the message
  var modalDiv = document.createElement("div");
  modalDiv.id = "loadingModal";
  modalDiv.style.position = "fixed";
  modalDiv.style.top = "50%";
  modalDiv.style.left = "50%";
  modalDiv.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)";
  modalDiv.style.background = "#74889b";
  modalDiv.style.padding = "20px";
  modalDiv.style.border = "1px solid #46596c";
  modalDiv.style.color = "#fff";
  modalDiv.innerHTML = message;

  // Add the div to the page
  document.body.appendChild(modalDiv);
}


var modalDiv=document.getElementById('loadingModal56'); - so where is an element with the ID loadingModal56 supposed to come from? I see you assinging modalDiv.id = "loadingModal"; to one of the dynamically created elements, but I can't spot any place where you would add a numeric suffix after that? Or was this element supposed to exist in the initial HTML this operates on already?

Sorry I fixed now my question. That was an issue with the cache. I'm testing on two different websites... I edited the whole questions with all details pertinent to the issue.
Thank you in advance.
Max.

"Argument 1 is not an object." - if that is referring to modalDiv.appendChild(progressBarElement);, then the issue is not that modalDiv doesn't exist at that point, but that progressBarElement doesn't actually refer to an HTML element. Which probably has to do with the fact, that you are explicitly removing this element from the DOM and setting this variable to null, in stopProgressBar.

Hello C3 roe and thank you.
How can I avoid that ? Should I remove any reference of progressBarElement in the stopProgressBar function, here:
function stopProgressBar() {
if (progressBarElement) {
progressBarElement.parentNode.removeChild(progressBarElement);
}
